# call canvas in oracle form 6i

Tags: forms

i have many canvases in one form 
i want to know how the button (when pressed)exchange between the canvases
  like if i want call forms the syntax is call_form
but i don't know to call canvases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move to the canvas, you should move to another block, this block must have an item that show in the canvas that you want to show.

```
Go_Block('Name_Block');
```